# Output certain text into DIV using Ajax in Wordpress

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I'm very new to Ajax. Through a lot of trial an error, I have a basic example and I'm looking to expand it.

I'm working on a custom Wordpress page with an image map of the USA and I need to use Ajax to fill in a div with information on each state.

When a user clicks on the map area defined to be New York an href is triggered like:
`href="javascript:getStateInfo('newyork')"`

Here is my JS function:

```
function getStateInfo(name)
    {
        var name = this.name;
        jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
    data: {
        action: name, // the PHP function to run
    },
    success: function(data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
        jQuery('#infoDiv').html(''); // empty an element
        jQuery('#infoDiv').append(data); // put our list of links into it
    },
    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        if(typeof console === "undefined") {
            console = {
                log: function() { },
                debug: function() { },
            };
        }
        if (XMLHttpRequest.status == 404) {
            console.log('Element not found.');
        } else {
            console.log('Error: ' + errorThrown);
        }
    }
});}
```

I'm looking to get the information with ajax so in my functions.php file I have

```
function newyork()
{
    echo 'this is info on new york state';
    die();
}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_newyork', 'newyork' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_newyork', 'newyork' );
```

Obviously this code doesn't work, and I'm not even sure if I should be writing 50 different functions with `add_action`'s for each state. If anyone knows of a better way to implement this, I'm really eager to learn how to implement this most efficiently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually really simple and you don't even need to use aJax at all for this.

However you define the area for the maps your js can look like this

```
$('.state').on('click', function(){
    var state = $(this).val();
    $('#display').append(state);
});
```

You can also add in `$('#display').empty();` to clear the current data inside of the #display element before adding in the new data.

Here is the code that you could edit to load in a page with the text that you would like on it

```
$('.state').on('click', function(){
    var state = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'goes here',
        data: {state : state},
        success: function(displayState){
            $('#display').html(displayState);
        }
    )};
});
```

The page that you load in could then be written to display info depending on which state you clicked.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! This is much simpler. If I want to use javascript append text from a file in the stylesheet uri directory, how would I write that?

Comment: That is when you would add in ajax and set the url to the location of the file that you want to load into the #display element. Ill write up a quick example of how that ajax would look with the above code.

Comment: Answer updated. From here its building the file that you send which state you selected too and the best way would be to build it in php and use a switch statement for the states(would be a crap ton of code if you used if/else statements).

Comment: Thanks very much! I ended up using a switch statement and this for each case: 

$('#display').empty(); 
$("#display").load("textFile.txt #informationDiv");